# Java Selenium Chromedriver.exe Does not Exist IllegalStateException

Tags: java, selenium

Here is the error message I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Users\Scott\workspace\Twitch%20Bot%20v2\bin\chromedriver.exe
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:197)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:117)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$0(ChromeDriverService.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:118)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:291)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:117)
    at com.fatalcubez.main.Bot.setup(Bot.java:41)
    at com.fatalcubez.main.Bot.<init>(Bot.java:29)
    at com.fatalcubez.main.BotGUI.<init>(BotGUI.java:17)
    at com.fatalcubez.main.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

And here is the code that I'm using:

```
ClassLoader loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        URL path = loader.getResource("chromedriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", path.getPath());
```

I've already check the directory for where it is searching for the chromedriver and it's there. I'm not sure what the problem is at this point. Any help would be great!

EDIT: It was simply a problem with spacing in the folder name, but now I have another problem. When I try to launch chrome it says "An administrator has installed chrome on this computer...." What can I do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to give your chromeDriver.exe file path instead of taking the path from the URL.

example:

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Answer (score 16):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "/home/vin/Downloads/chromedriver");
```

Note- write the chromedriver without mentioning .exe (In **Ubuntu** and **Mac**)

Answer (score 1):

Download the chromedriver:

[chromedriver link](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.38/)

From here unzip the folder and copy choromedriver.exe in c now set path like

[image: sample image]

Answer (score 1):

Locate your chrome driver file ( for windows) in the C drive under the user and the name of your device. Using any random folder and directing to that path will not work.

`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\hp\\chromedriver.exe");`

This works for me, and I think the reason is, the driver will search for the path that identifies your pc, like a default folder where they search for, as it will be more time consuming to search for random folders and can create errors when you have multiple copies of that `chromedriver.exe` file like I had. Thanks, hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to add, when using chromedriver with windows, you must include .exe in your systems properties call.

valid call : `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "res/chromedriver.exe");`

invalid call : `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "res/chromedriver");`

Answer (score 0):

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\Downloads\chromedriver.exe");

Navigate to this path, right click and open the chromedriver.exe then a pop up is open Uncheck "the Always ask before open" . 
this works for me

Answer (score 0):

In `mac OS` set the path as follows

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "/Users/'user_name'/Downloads/chromedriver");
```

go to System preferences, in Security and privacy General tab you will see open `chromedriver` anyway, click on it and run your program again.

It works for me

Answer (score -1):

You can add the address of chrome driver exe in your code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
        "/path where exe is present/chromedriver.exe");
```

or you can directly copy paste the exe of chrome driver in you workspace (`C:\Users\Scott\workspace\Twitch Bot v2\bin\`)

Answer (score -1):

This  worked for me:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "//Users//alinapanigrahi//bin//chromedriver");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
```

But I got the unknown error:

```
unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"686.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
```

Comment: duplicate answer