# Selenium i couldn't the run java application on selenium

Tags: selenium, exception

When trying to run the class, the following  error shows:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver
>   executable does not exist: C:\Users\imper\Downloads.exe

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Selenium Chromedriver.exe Does not Exist IllegalStateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30688368/java-selenium-chromedriver-exe-does-not-exist-illegalstateexception)

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.