# Can not configure Selenium with Jenkins

Tags: git, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using the centos 7 & facing issue while integrating selenium with Jenkins.

I've written below selenium script which on my local machine is properly executing.

I've tomcat running on port 8081 and this script is working on it.

The script is below -

```
public class App 
{

@Test
public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/home/amrut/Documents/chromedriver"); 
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions(); 

//      chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions); 

    System.out.println("Hi, Welcome to  YouTube Live session on Selenium WebDriver"); 

    driver.get("http://localhost:8081/addressbook"); 
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.className("v-button")).click(); 
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("gwt-uid-5")).sendKeys("temp"); 
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("gwt-uid-7")).sendKeys("DevOps");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("gwt-uid-9")).sendKeys("9834562709");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("gwt-uid-11")).sendKeys("Devops@temp.co");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("gwt-uid-13")).sendKeys("01/01/2015");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.className("v-button-primary")).click(); 
    Thread.sleep(3000); 
    driver.quit();    

    System.out.println("Done....");
}
}
```

Now, if I run this locally through Eclipse, it is working fine.

I've Exported the runnable jar file from this and I've uploaded it to the Git repository.While creating the jar file uncommented the headless chromeoptions line from my code.

Also, this local Jar file is working fine from my local command line.

Now I'm creating the Jenkin's Job which will fetch this GIT repo & in the Build section I've selected the **Execute shell** & passed the below command to it -

```
java -jar "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Selenium Demo/App1_test.jar"

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /home/amrut/Documents/chromedriver
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:585)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:136)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:33)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:139)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:335)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:89)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
at com.amrut.SeleniumDemo.App.main(App.java:26)
... 5 more
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I'm pretty sure that my chromedriver exist in the path /home/amrut/Documents/chromedriver
but not sure why am I getting this error?

Please assist. I tried with lot of options but still not able to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Selenium Chromedriver.exe Does not Exist IllegalStateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30688368/java-selenium-chromedriver-exe-does-not-exist-illegalstateexception)

Comment: @user7294900 I'm facing this issue while integrating selenium with jenkins. Locally it is running fine.

Comment: Try to keep your Chromedriver.exe in the Project Folder and do a try!!!!

Comment: @Ab123, I'm on Centos. I did this as well but somehow It's not getting placed into the JAR file. So Jenkins can't figure it out. I added it into the GIT repo itself. But still Jenkins faces the access issues. Once access writes are given manually but It again fails.

Comment: @Amrut, do you have the right chromedriver in the path? Is it Linux version of chromedriver?

Comment: @Abhilash Yes it is right chromedriver. As mentioned in description it's working fine when run it through locally on Eclipse it's working fine.

Comment: @Amrut, do you have the chromedriver log file?