# chromedriver executable not found in TFS for Maven Selenium Project

Tags: java, maven, selenium, tfs

On running my Java Selenium tests through Maven build(POM.xml) in TFS2015, getting error. I understand error is for chromedriver executable but not sure what path I should give.

This path is currently used when I run through eclipse-D:\DATA\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe
For Running through TFS what changes should I do?

Also, Maven setup is done in TFS and in POM.xml I mentioned all dependenices. So, for chromedriver.exe do I have to do some extra setup in TFS. Please help.

Error I am getting is-

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: D:\DATA\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:585)
```

POM.xml is as follows-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>Maven_demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>Maven_Project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>Maven_Project</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-plugin-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [3.2,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>descriptor</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: Is the chromedriver executable file present in the path `D:\DATA\chromedriver_win32` on your **build agent machine**?

Comment: @ Cece Dong - MSFT  -no that is my local machine path.. I have to give build agent machine path there? and for chrome browser binary ..where it will pick from?

Comment: Check here: http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add the following code to your Selenium program before creating a new instance of ChromeDriver:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
```

In case the solution above does not work, try to download/Change chrome driver as per chrome browser version on your build agent machine.

Useful links:

- [Java Selenium Chromedriver.exe Does not Exist IllegalStateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30688368/java-selenium-chromedriver-exe-does-not-exist-illegalstateexception)
- https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-solve-this-The-driver-executable-does-not-exist-error-in-selenium