# Cannot find chrome driver on Jenkins server

Tags: google-chrome, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, selenium-chromedriver, jenkins-pipeline

The issue that I am running into is that I cannot find the chrome driver on my Jenkins server. I am trying to run my selenium tests using the chrome driver.

Here is what I have tried so far:
1. Checked the version of Google Chrome that is installed
2. Commands that I have tried so far

> ```
> which google-chrome 
> google-chrome --version 
> google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot --window-size=1280,1696
> ```

Here is the error that I am receiving:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Selenium Chromedriver.exe Does not Exist IllegalStateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30688368/java-selenium-chromedriver-exe-does-not-exist-illegalstateexception)

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30702254/5900683

Comment: Thank you for your response. 

For clarification:
Since I am using a linux slave, the path will be different, right?

The solution above would work for windows.

Comment: have you checked the location exists and if you have permission to it?